# How to avoid invalid error in ModelState when deserializing a json

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm writing an API controller with C#. I'm leveraging the ModelState to do the model validation. E.g. checking the length of a string field, or checking if an int field exceed the maximum.

But I found an issue, sometimes it does not work as expected. For example, here I have a model with two fields:

```
public int A { get; set; }
public bool B { get; set; }
```

Then my request payload looks like following:

```
{
   "A": 123.4,
   "B": true
}
```

Obviously the A is in a invalid format, it should be int but I gave it a float. So I got an error in ModelState: `Input string '123.4' is not a valid integer. Path 'A', line x, position x.`. This totally make sense.

But another error occurs in the ModelState at the same time: `Unexpected token when deserializing object: Boolean. Path 'B', line x, position x.`.

It seems that when A is not an int, C# will have errors in deserializing the rest part of the json. How could I avoid this? I hope there's only the first error in the ModelState.

Thank you all!

------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

Many thanks for the help. I'd like to add some comments here. For sure I used `ModelState.IsValid` to check if the payload is valid. And the result is false. Which is correct. But the mistake here is, only the first field A is invalid, but B is valid. So I wish to have only A's error in the ModelState.

Comment: You can use an if statement in your api controller to check if ModelState.IsValid

Comment: Thank you @Jawad, I applied it. And it return false. But it contains two errors, which is incorrect for me. A is invalid but B should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way if ModelState.IsValid is not working properly:

```
private int _a;
public int A
{
    get
    {
        return _a;
    }
    set
    {
        bool success = Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int number);
        if (success)
        {
            _a = number;
        }

    }
}
```

if not using .net core 3 then just declare int number; above the try parse and remove the int from there

```
int number
```

bool success = Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out number);
        if (success)
        {
            _a = number;
        }

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the validity (whether thats one property or all properties), i have always used the following if statement. This normally covers the request with 1 or more errors and returns a BadRequest status.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

If you are interested in running tests and making sure all properties are correct, I can suggest using `TestController` type of class that would validate the data.

[Read Here](https://alenjalex.github.io/dev/dev/Asp.Net-Core-ModelState-Validation-Using-UnitTest/) for details on how to set that up. Lots of examples here.